# MySQL: Attempting to select table based on CASE, receiving Error Code: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, case

I'm trying to create a query which returns the relevant table (cld) based on the present value for a specific item in another table (oss) - however, currently receiving "Error Code: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)" with the below query:

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN oss.`creative_link_data` IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM `facebook_creative_link_data`)
END 
FROM adgroup a
JOIN `creative` c ON c.`parent_id` = a.`uuid`
LEFT JOIN `facebook_object_story_spec` oss ON oss.`id` = c.`object_story_spec`
LEFT JOIN `facebook_creative_link_data` cld ON cld.`id` = oss.`creative_link_data`
WHERE TRUE
AND a.`uuid` = 12345
;
```

Attempting to select just the ID column from the table results in this error "Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row"

However, removing the case and just selecting the ID returns only 1 row.

Is this a syntax error? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

for avoid the problem related  to the subquery result you should select a column and limit the number of rows result to 1

```
  SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN oss.`creative_link_data` IS NOT NULL THEN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM `facebook_creative_link_data`
        LIMIT 1)
  END 
  FROM adgroup a
  JOIN `creative` c ON c.`parent_id` = a.`uuid`
  LEFT JOIN `facebook_object_story_spec` oss ON oss.`id` = c.`object_story_spec`
  LEFT JOIN `facebook_creative_link_data` cld ON cld.`id` = oss.`creative_link_data`
  WHERE TRUE
  AND a.`uuid` = 12345
  ;
```

anyway you case condition should be result using a INNER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM adgroup a
JOIN `creative` c ON c.`parent_id` = a.`uuid`
LEFT JOIN `facebook_object_story_spec` oss ON oss.`id` = c.`object_story_spec`
INNER  JOIN `facebook_creative_link_data` cld ON cld.`id` = oss.`creative_link_data`
WHERE TRUE
AND a.`uuid` = 12345
;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Subquery you're trying to fetch more than one row and it contain more than one column. So you should use like this - `SELECT id FROM facebook_creative_link_data Limit 1`